# Unset all array elements past certain element in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$example = array('First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth',...
```

The code below will unset the third element in `$example`.

```
unset($example[2]);
```

How can I `unset` all of the elements past the third element?

I want `$example`'s value to be this afterwards:

```
$example = array('First','Second','Third');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use unset, use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$example = array('First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth');
array_splice($example,3);
//$example = array('First','Second','Third');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) for this.

```
$example = array('First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth');
array_splice($example, 3);
var_dump($example);

array
  0 => string 'First' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Second' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Third' (length=5)
```

Comment: you didn't have to downvote my post just because I got to it faster. :)

Comment: I had downvoted it because it was wrong. It returns the extracted values (Fourth, Fifth) and you were showing that, not the ones OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
for ($i = count($array); $i > 3; $i--)
{
    array_pop($array);
}
```